# Restrict customer to view the page before successful payment Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have created a page in my custom module and i want to so that page after successful payment of the of the product.

Kindly suggest for how can i implement a payment restriction method that can check the payment is successfully done for the product and then the corresponding customer can be access the same page.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Was my answer useful? Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For action to give customer access to certain page after succesfull payment, use an observer for event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.

Your module config.xml should look like:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
        <!-- ... -->
        <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_module>
                        <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                        <method>yourMethod</method>
                    </namespace_module>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>
        <!-- ... -->
    </global>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

Create namespace/module/Model/Observer.php. This file should look like:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function yourMethod($observer)
    {
         // Your code logic to give customer access to required page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In your module create an observer for the event 'sales_order_payment_pay'
2. Also in your module install file create a new customer attribute. You can use this tutorial http://magentotutorial.org/how-to-add-new-customer-attributes-in-magento/ or search for another (you can find a lot of examples on google on how to install attributes with your module). Make sure the attribute is not visible on frontend
3. Inside the event function when a customer payed for an order check if that specific product was in that order. If it was, edit the customer and add some value (true, or whatever you want) in the newly created attribute. If you need to monitor for multiple products you can save an array inside that attribute by serialising it.
4. When viewing that custom page (controller action) check for the customer attribute and check if he is allowed to view it

Answer (score -1):

You can create observer and find event

http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

Suggested event :

sales_order_payment_place_end

sales_order_payment_capture

sales_order_payment_pay